existing psycopg2 mock cursor, or consistent method of converting csv data to its python
I am using a postgres database, I store some critical application data from the database on csvs in the case that my database crashes or the endpoint goes down. The csvs are a reflection of the tables. I use psycopg2 to get all rows in a table and write them to csv.
This example table:
CREATE TABLE user
name VARCHAR(255)
age INTEGER;

Would be this csv:



name
age




1043
23


Jack
10


Jill
11



The number value preceding the actual data represents the type_code pyscopg2 uses internally to convert data from the database to a corresponding python type.
My plan was to use these numbers to access the psycopg2 _type associated with the csv column and perform a type conversion using that interface.
df = pd.read_csv("user.csv")

for column in df:
    type_code, column_data = int(df[column][0]), df[column] # (1043, ["Jack", "Jill"])
    for element in column_data[1:]:
        typed_element = psycopg2.extensions.string_types[type_code](element,None)
        # ... 

Unfortunately as illustrated by this excellent stackoverflow answer string based types require a cursor to perform a type conversion.
Passing in None here instead of a cursor causes a segmentation fault, but only for types that aren't strings.
I'm loading these csvs under the assumption that I won't be able to connect to the database and can't create a cursor.
For now, my band-aid solution is to just ignore string types since I already have the data as a string.
cursor_dependent_type_codes = [25, 1043] # This is not exhaustive just what I've encountered.

for column in df:
    type_code, column_data = int(df[column][0]), df[column] # (1043, ["Jack", "Jill"])
    if type_code in cursor_dependent_type_codes:
        # Handle raw string value manually
        continue
    for element in column_data[1:]:
        typed_element = psycopg2.extensions.string_types[type_code](element, None)
        # ... 

However if a cursor becomes necessary for any of the more esoteric postgres types I would like to have a better solution to this problem, other than trying to restrict my team to not use types that can trigger a segfault. Especially for code that will only run when the app needs to be more resilient.
A solution suggested by the referenced post's author is to use a mock cursor that exposes the methods required for string conversions. To my knowledge no such thing exists and this feature really isn't worth the time it would take to implement one.

Why not just use pg_dump. pg_dump -d some_db -U some_user -t a _table -a would get you a data only dump from the table in format you could use to reload the data. For more then one table do -t a_table -t b_table and so on.

I may have been unclear. The csvs aren't backups and I'm not trying to recreate a database with them. To be specific I have a table that I query to check user configurations for the application. The csvs are copies of that table that are to be used in case the database fails or has downtime.


... I store some critical application data from the database on csvs in the case that my database crashes or the endpoint goes down. sounds like a backup to me. 2) The pg_dump -a format will be in CSV like format. 3)  If you want to do in psycopg2 then use copy_expert. CSV is a text format, assuming you are putting the data back in the same fields that will not cause and issue. Trying to maintain type information is a case of premature optimization and really not worth the effort.

